# How to view text file in Firefox window without downloading it?

Tags: firefox, download, video-streaming, mime-types

I want to see the content of a .m3u8 file without downloading it. I remember reading this trick somewhere, but I can't remember exactly where.

What I do remember, is that it involves adding special keywords at the beginning of the URL (eg. the file is located at `http://example.com/yyy.m3u8` so the link you paste into address bar is `something://example.com/yyy.m3u8` or `something-http://example.com/yyy.m3u8`). After this the file content shows in browser window.

This doesn't change the MIME or content type, it just does this temporarily. I can't find the trick anywhere because all the tutorials I can find are about teaching you how to change this in the Firefox file type option, or changing the MIME type files in your profiles folder.

Comment: SuperUser requires that posts are in Q&A format. Please move the short edit at the bottom of your question to its own answer (and mark it as accepted).

Comment: @joejoe31b can't find my own 'edit' answer now ... but isn't it forbidden or "not recommended" to answer my own question ? last time i did this, i got a -1 message ...

Comment: On one of the SuperUser help pages it says that they encourage people to answer their own questions. I think the problem is that you don't have enough reputation. For more information, have a look here: http://superuser.com/help/self-answer.

Comment: oh i don't have enough reputation, maybe someone can paste my answers here.

Comment: _Users with less than 100 reputation must wait 8 hours before answering their own question if they do not instant-self-answer._ ou should be able to post an answer in another 5 hours or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend the url with `view-source:` like `view-source:http://example.com/yyy.m3u8`

Comment: i figured out this already ! thanks all the same ! ( i don't care about points )

Comment: `view-source:https://sourceforge.net/p/fakedetector/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/fakebase/src/codecvt_iconv.h?format=raw` does not work with Firefox 75.0b12

Comment: Just tested with Firefox v123 and it works.